# Return array from function -conflicting types for

Tags: c, arrays

My purpose is to create an array in a function and then return it to the main function. 
I was recommended to allocate the array on the heap in the function (otherwise popped from the stack as soon as its returned).

The code is shown below:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 int main() {

    double *v1 = myFunction();

    return 0;
 }



 double *myFunction() {
   return malloc(10*sizeof(double));
 }
```

When I compile this code with gcc I get the following error-message:

```
 ..\src\main3.c:38:9: error: conflicting types for 'myFunction'
```

What is wrong with this code? Why do I get this compilation error?

Comment: Prototype declaration of the function is required before you can use the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)  Add prototype of `myfunction` at the starting like following or

```
double *myFunction();
 int main() {
    double *v1 = myFunction();
    return 0;
 }
 double *myFunction() {
   return malloc(10*sizeof(double));
 }
```

2). or define the functionBody before it is called

```
 double *myFunction() {
   return malloc(10*sizeof(double));
 }

 int main() {
    double *v1 = myFunction();
    return 0;
 }
```

However, first solution is preferable.

Comment: just so simple :-O .... missing to declare the prototype. I am used to java - thats why ... thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

Provide `myFunction()`'s prototype before using it, that is before `main()` like so:

```
double * myFunction();

int main(void)
{
  ...
```

If not doing so, the compiler assumes type `int` for `myFunction()` when seeing it for the first time.

Than later it finds it to be declared as `double *` (being different from `int`) which then provokes the error.

Turning on all warnings would have pointed you to using a function without prototype. Use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to turn on most of gcc's warnings.

---

Another issue is that declaring a function without any arguments specified leaves it open what to pass on calling the function:

```
double * myFunction();
```

If a function should be specfied to **not** have any arguments specify `void` as argument:

```
double * myFunction(void);
```

The same for how your code defines `main()`. It shall be:

```
int main(void);
```

or either be

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost fine, there's only one little but blocking error, you are trying to use myFunction before the symbol is defined, all you have to do is :

```
#include <stdlib.h>
double *myFunction() { // myFunction should be declared before it's used
    return malloc(10*sizeof(double));
}

int main() {
    double *v1 = myFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

The the open C book states ["All identifiers in C need to be declared before they are used. This is true for functions as well as variables."](http://opencbp.sourceforge.net/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/opencbook/func.prototypes.html)  the beauty in C is that you can do can do amazing stuff like [this piece of code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duff%27s_device), but you should follow some guidelines, read the open C book!.

Cheers.

Answer (score -1):

Try this..

```
 return (double*) malloc(10*sizeof(double));
```

Comment: The `void *` returned by `malloc()` is implcitly converted to `double *` on return of the function. **No** need to cast.

Comment: NO! I got the error below if I do not add..

 error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'void *' to 'double *'
1>        Conversion from 'void*' to pointer to non-'void' requires an explicit cast

Comment: So you were using a C++ compiler but a C one. The question is tagged C.